# How do I auto resize an AVPlayerLayer to show the video in its full size on the whole parent view in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerlayer

Im trying to display a video using the `AVPlayerLayer` on top of a `UIImage`. The video is supposed to resize itself so that the **full** video is shown on the image view, even if it has to stretch itself to do it.
Unfortunately I dont get those results, my video end up looking like this instead on the simulator.
[Image of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1I14.jpg)

Ive tried setting the AVPlayerLayer.frame manual to the image views size, to demonstrate what im aiming for it to look like on all the diffrent iPhone sizes.
[Image of the goal results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ReIg3.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: queuePlayer)
playerLayer.frame = feedBackground.bounds
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
feedBackground.layer.masksToBounds = true
feedBackground.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
```

(feedBackground is a UIImage)

dont know if its important but feedBackground's contentMode is scale to fill

Im quite new to app development so thanks for taking you time to read my question and thanks for any solutions you may have :)

Comment: Your two image look almost the same, and it's not at all clear what's supposed to be the "feedBackground" image and what's supposed to be the video.

Comment: Sorry my fault for not including all the code, feedBackground is the UIImage which i add the AVPlayerLayer to which contains a AVQueuePlayer that contains the video. feedBackground is a image that i created in the storyboard. But its all good i found out why it wasn't working :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, i found out a solution.
I was integrating the video in viewDidLoad and was setting the playerLayer.frame to be equal to feedBackground.bounds - i think the reason why it wasn't working was bcs the graphics hadn't loaded yet so i couldn't set my videos frame to be equal to feedBackgrounds frame bcs feedBackgrounds frame wasn't calculated / made yet.

Maybe am wrong, either way it worked by moving my code to viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.